# passing index columns to sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I've created a DateTransformer class which extracts features such as year, month etc from a pd.TimeStamp, the following works fine when 'timestamp' is a column

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

ct = ColumnTransformer([("date", DateTransformer(),['timestamp'])])
ct.fit_transform(data)
```

However in my case, timestamp is actually an index level, so instead of accessing the columns collection, I need ColumnTransformer to do the following

```
data.index.get_level_values('timestamp')
```

I can do a `pd.reset_index()` but I was wondering if there's another way?

Comment: Did you mean `df.index.get_level_values("timestamp")`?

Comment: @Evan yes, I'll fix that

Comment: Sorry, a little confused - is `get_level_values` not returning data you can use, or were you asking if there is an alternative to using it at all? (Not sure what your data looks like.)

Comment: Hi @Evan no I'm specifically asking about sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer and if it can be used to access columns which are part of the index. It doesn't appear so, I've created a workaround where I drop in the index before applying the pipeline and that works